# ReactJS - Passing object every 30 seconds from parent to child component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I am making a game like application where from Game.js file i am passing object to child GameIntro.js file every 3 seconds but it seems i am unable to do it through below code.
My intention is that every 3 seconds different objects should pass to child component and remove the previous passed component.

## Game.js file::

```
import React from 'react';
import {gdatas} from './gamedata';
import GameIntro from './GameIntro';


const Game = () => {
    // const [item, setItem] = useState();
    return (
        <div>
            {gdatas && gdatas.map((gdata,i) => {
                return setInterval(() => (
                    <GameIntro key={i} gdata={gdata} />
                ),2000)
            }
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Game;
```

## GameIntro.js file

```
import React from 'react';
// import {gdatas} from './gamedata';

const GameIntro = ({gdata}) => {

    const gameData = gdata.data.map((elm,i) => {
        return (
        <div className="col-md-6" key={i}>
            <div className="card">
                <img src={elm.image} className="card-img-top img-fluid" 
                    alt={elm.word} style={{'width' : '350px' , 'height' : '350px'}} />
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title mt-3">{elm.word}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    })
    return (
        <div className="row">
            {gameData }
        </div>
    )
}
export default GameIntro;
```

Comment: `setInterval` returns a number. If you want to change state - use `useState`

Comment: `setInterval` returns an id. It doesn't make sense to return it as part of `.map`.

Comment: okay but how to pass the object from map every 3 second ?

Comment: You don't, `.map` is the wrong tool here.

Comment: @ArjunKumar if you need to change state every 3 seconds - call `useState` every 3 seconds and pass the changed data there.

Comment: I would recommend using a global state instead of the react state. window.interval = setInterval(doSomething, ms); React state changes can be hard to manage (or maybe Redux)

Comment: Let me try and then come because its a very interesting problem.

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` returns an id. It doesn't make sense to return it as part of `.map`. You can use `setState` and start the interval once (here I'm simulating an interval with `setTimeout`):

```js
import React from 'react';
import {gdatas} from './gamedata';
import GameIntro from './GameIntro';


const Game = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = React.useState();

    React.useEffect(() => {
       let id;
       function next(i) {
         id = setTimeout(function() {
            if (i < gdatas.length) {
              setState(gdatas[i]);
              next(i+1);
            }
         }, 2000);
       }
       next(0);
       return () => clearTimeout(id);
    }, []); // only invoke on first render


    return (
        <div>
            {item && <GameIntro gdata={item} />}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Game;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't render the child each item on each loop, just update the **props** on it. It's actually pretty trivial once you see how:

Example below:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";

const GameObject = (props) => (
  <div className="bar">
    {props.current.name}
  </div>
)

function App() {
  const data = [{name: 'Luke'}, {name: 'Darth'}, {name: 'Yoda'}];
  let index = useRef(0);
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(data[index.current]);

  useEffect(() => {
      function loop() {
        setInterval(() => {
          index.current = (index.current === data.length - 1) ? 0 : index.current + 1;
          setCurrent(data[index.current]);
        }, 1000);
      }

      loop();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GameObject current={current}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```